# Strategies for Postgres pg_catalog constant lookups

Tags: postgresql, catalog

**Short version:** 
I'm spending some time in pg_catalog, and want to display expanded definitions where char codes are used. For example "composite type" instead of "c" for pg_class.relkind. I've tried custom functions, and a lookup soup table. I'm hoping to get some suggestions and, likely, pointers to obvious things I've overlooked.

Postgres 11.5, deployment on RDS (no superuser.)

**Longer version:** 
For our project, I'm writing a fair few client-side code generators and reporting screens, which means I need to dig into pg_type, pg_class, pg_attribute and more. For what I assume are historical reasons, a lot of the table and column names in pg_catalog are....opaque. And a good number of fields include character codes that either need to be looked up or memorized.  For example, pg_class.relkind holds one of the values I, S, c, f, i, m, p, r, t, or v. Eh? I could memorize what those mean and translate them in my head, but that's something the computer can do more easily. So, I figured I'd write a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.relkind_name (relkind text, out relkind_name text)
  RETURNS text
 AS $$
SELECT CASE
  WHEN relkind = 'r' THEN 'table'
  WHEN relkind = 'i' THEN 'index'
  WHEN relkind = 'S' THEN 'sequence'
  WHEN relkind = 't' THEN 'TOAST table'
  WHEN relkind = 'v' THEN 'view'
  WHEN relkind = 'm' THEN 'materialized view'
  WHEN relkind = 'c' THEN 'composite type'
  WHEN relkind = 'f' THEN 'foreign table'
  WHEN relkind = 'p' THEN 'partitioned table'
  WHEN relkind = 'I' THEN 'partitioned index'
  ELSE 'Unexpected relkind ' || relkind
END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

ALTER FUNCTION data.relkind_name (relkind text, out relkind_name text) OWNER TO user_bender;
```

That's...fine. It works, but I don't love functions like this for a couple of reasons 1) The data is baked into code, not a data structure. So, you can't reuse/display/validate it in any way. 2)I'll need a custom function for each constant type. Which brings me to the next idea, a lookup soup table.

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data.constant CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.constant (
    theme text NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    code text NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    label text NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (theme, code)
);

ALTER TABLE data.constant OWNER TO user_change_structure;
COMMIT;
```

Before going further, I'll stipulate that **grab-all lookup tables are generally worthy of derision**. It's *not* something I would do with dynamic, user-driven data. Because bad. So bad. But in this one, narrow, case, it seems like a solid idea:

- The data is baked into Postgres and changes only with major releases, if then.
- None of this data will ever go away, or at least not likely.
- It's super easy to add a new set of constants, once I run into something of interest.

Here's some setup for a couple of the constants lists in pg_catalog:

```
INSERT INTO constant
    (theme,code,label)

VALUES
    ('typcategory','A','Array types'),
    ('typcategory','B','Boolean types'),
    ('typcategory','C','Composite types'),
    ('typcategory','D','Date/time types'),
    ('typcategory','E','Enum types'),
    ('typcategory','G','Geometric types'),
    ('typcategory','I','Network address types'),
    ('typcategory','N','Numeric types'),
    ('typcategory','P','Pseudo-types'),
    ('typcategory','R','Range types'),
    ('typcategory','S','String types'),
    ('typcategory','T','Timespan types'),
    ('typcategory','U','User-defined types'),
    ('typcategory','V','Bit-string types'),
    ('typcategory','X','unknown type'),
    ('relkind','r','ordinary table'),
    ('relkind','i','index'),
    ('relkind','S','sequence'),
    ('relkind','t','TOAST table'),
    ('relkind','v','view'),
    ('relkind','m','materialized view'),
    ('relkind','c','composite type'),
    ('relkind','f','foreign table'),
    ('relkind','p','partitioned table'),
    ('relkind','I','partitioned index');
```

Since the data is in a table, you can do normal things in a normal way. Or even use Postgres' wonderful string_agg function:

```
  select theme,
         string_agg(code, ', ' order by code) as constants 
    from constant 
group by theme
order by theme;

relkind I, S, c, f, i, m, p, r, t, v
typcategory A, B, C, D, E, G, I, N, P, R, S, T, U, V, X
```

Or a simple query to do the lookup:

```
-- I want a default/error result label if there is no match.
select coalesce((select label from constant where theme = 'relkind' and code  = 'X'),
                'Undefined')
```

Which can be wrapped into a function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS data.lookup (theme text, code text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.lookup (theme text, code text)
    RETURNS TEXT 
AS $$
-- I want a default/error result label if there is no match, hence the subquery.
select coalesce(
                (select label 
                   from constant 
                  where theme = $1 and
                        code  = $2),
                'Undefined')
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

ALTER FUNCTION data.lookup (theme text, code text)  OWNER TO user_bender;
```

And then, finally, a query on a catalog table that gives human-readable results:

```
select relowner::regrole,
        relnamespace::regnamespace,
        relname,
        lookup('relkind',relkind) as relkind_name,
        reltype::regtype

  from pg_class
```

You'll see from the above that I found some of the oid magic casting tools, and some of the system information functions. I'm looking to use the lookup() function to fill in some gaps.

I'd be grateful for commentary or suggestions, even if that amounts to "throw all of that out, there's a better way."

For the record, I checked out custom types, magic::castings, CREATE DOMAIN (doesn't apply), ENUM (doesn't apply and doesn't appeal.) I'm currently ruling out building a bunch of custom views as it feels like that would make reworking my code harder for the next person. (The one lookup function doesn't seem like too much to learn.)

Comment: I would go for the first function (and define it as `immutable` for performance reasons). Easier to maintain, easier to understand and less code than your other solutions. I don't see why it shouldn't be "reusable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the way you want, and if your taste buds react better to a single lookup table, so be it.

I get the impression that your motivation is partly playfulness, since after some exposure you will be able to memorize the frequent one-letter codes with ease.

In that vein, I suggest playing with types some more:

You could create a custom type whose internal representation is just like `"char"`, but the type output function produces the long description. The type input function would understand both the single character strings and the long name.

There would be such types for `relkind` and the other short codes.

Then you create `IMPLICIT` casts `WITHOUT FUNCTION` between `"char"` and the new types. If you want, you can also create (`EXPLICIT`) casts to and from `text`.

The whole thing will be pretty similar to the `regclass`, `regtype` and related convenience types.

If nothing else, it is a nice introduction to hacking PostgreSQL.

Comment: "Playfulness", nicely put. Yes, I'm largely doing this to get my hands dirty in the pg_catalog details in hopes of assimilating them. I find your idea intriguing, something like:

relkind::relkindname

This is very much what I wanted to do, you nailed it. I tried this out yesterday, and sort of got it to work. As far as I could figure, I have to use a custom compound type when what I really want is an alias for char. With a custom CREATE TYPE, then I can have a function based CREATE CAST.

Comment: I think I lost my experiments, but off of the top of my head, it was something like this:

CREATE TYPE relkindname AS (label text);
CREATE CAST (char as relkindname) with function relkind_get_name(char);
I didn't get this to work smoothly. The input and output types seemed pretty fussy, and using a composite type with one attribute has an unwelcome consequence. It seems that when you convert a composite (even a row) type, you get (parens)

Comment: select table_name::text from table_name; 
That gets you the row converted to text, but with parens. (As you would know.) I found the same for any composite type. So, relkind::relkindname might come back with (base) when my function is returning "base".

Obviously, I'm flailing around a bit and I didn't find any examples to help out.  Can you point me towards anything more specific? I'm learning from digging into these details no matter what. I'd like to understand casts batter to be able to convert a row to a specific format. Say, only three of five fields through a cast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was not thinking about a composite type, but a regular type implemented with C functions. Sounds daunting, but it would only be the type input and output functions in that case, everything else could be taken from `"char"`.

Comment: I was just checking on that. Yes, deploying on RDS, so no custom C code or superuser. I might try it out on my own anyway for learning, I've now found some quite detailed examples of creating new base types in C.

It would be sweet if CREATE TYPE at the SQL level allowed for a type alias system. 
 
CREATE TYPE (relkind name LIKE text); -- Or something like that

As it stands, composite types are a great help, but all I'm after is a way to make a signature for a CAST.